# Activiti dynamic called element

Tags: activiti, bpmn

Is it possible to have a dynamic call like this in `activity`?

```
<callActivity id="action" name="perform an action" calledElement="#MyService.getElement(Id)" />
```

Current code returns always `no processes deployed with key '...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the answer. 
Everything works once `$` is used instead of `#`.

```
<callActivity id="action" name="perform an action" calledElement="${MyService.getElement(Id)}" />
```